# The UIButton not responding as it should in single-view app in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, viewcontroller

The selector 'go' with IBAction return type is not responding correctly. If the button is clicked with the text field being empty i.e its value being nil , the flow should return the 'if' part and not 'else'. But it works fine when I click the button second time. what can be the problem ?

Below is the code from implementation file i.e. ViewController.m where I have implemented the go selector.

```
@synthesize textField = _textField;


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Clear the text field
    self.textField.text =nil;
}

NSString *s;

-(IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (self.textField.text == nil)
    {
        s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Enter Your Name First " ];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blank Field : "
                                                        message:s
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OKAY"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
    } 
    else
    {
        s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@ " , self.textField.text];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello "
                                                        message:s
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];    
    }
}
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe instead of `nil` test for `""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `nil` as your comparator I would instead use something more concrete like

```
if ([self.textfield.text length] > 0)
{

}
else
{

}
```